# What is the best way to embed JRE 8 Installation in the Installer for my app?

Tags: java, installation, wix

I have a java application and I created an installer using Wix Toolset. I added a check to my installer does have user installed Java and what is its version.

Now I don't know what to do if user doesn't have installed java.

- let my installer set up JRE 8 (the JRE installer will be in the application installer) after the user consent?

OR

- Is it more correct to just give the user a link to download the JRE 8 installer from Oracle official website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends.  Do you want the extra size and complexity of including Java?  Would your users know what to do if you didn't do it for them?

Another option is Self Contained deployment where you app has it's own isolated version of Java. Easier with some upsides and downsides that can be read here.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html

Comment: I didn't know that Oracle names it "self-contained packaging". So, they officially allow to embed JRE in installer... This guide doesn't can't help me because i dont use Ant, but may be I can put all JRE package in installer using Wix and its `heat` tool. Thank you for the link!